# Don't collapse the "(more)" box in the close votes queue after you pass a review audit

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close

In the close votes queue, there's that little "(more)" link you can click on to get a box that shows you the full text of the close-vote reason that is currently suggested for the question.

From:

[image]

To:

[image]

This is particularly useful for questions that already have off-topic close votes, since it lets you see which subcategory of off-topic close votes prior voters have selected.

Alas, when you pass a review audit, the box collapses, forcing you click on the "(more)" link again to make the box reappear. My delicate fingers can barely handle the added stress of dragging the mouse all the way to the "(more)" link to reopen the box, and so I request that a feature be added preventing the box from collapsing after a review audit.

(This might happen in other review queues, and it might also happen after failing a review audit; I haven't checked.)

Comment: This also happens if you hit the browser "Back" button to go to a review you just completed, then hit the "Next" button on the page.